# Determining the number of shifts performed in insertion sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to solve this question http://www.mycodeschool.com/work-outs/sorting/7
The question is to find **no of shifts in Insertion Sort.**

I have written the code but couldn't figure out where I am going wrong in logic

http://ideone.com/GGjZjw

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
// Include headers as needed

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Write your code here
int T,count,n,*a;
// int imin;
cin >> T;
int value,hole;

while(T--)
{
    cin >> n;
    count=0;
    a=new int[n];
    //reading the input array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    // considering the 0th element to be already sorted and
    // remaining list unsorted
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        value=a[i];
        hole=i;
        // shifting 
        while(hole>0&&a[hole-1]>value)
        {
            // 
            a[hole]=a[hole-1];
            hole=hole-1;
            count++;
        }
        a[hole]=value;
    }
    // cout << count<<endl;
}
// Return 0 to indicate normal termination
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: So what's your question? You say you're *"going wrong in logic"*. Is it not working? Is the number of shifts wrong? How do you know?

Comment: Did you mean to reset count to `0` at every iteration of your while loop?

Comment: `a=new int[n];` you have a memory leak

Comment: `a[hole]` what did you call me? :-)

Comment: I know it is not a swap operation. It is just for shifting

Comment: @JanWinkler  no of shift is asking for no of change in position of elements I am dry running my code which is giving me a wrong answer for example the test case `2,4,1,3,5 => 2,4,1,3,5 (0 shifts) => 1,2,4,3,5 (3 shifts - any change in position is shift) => 1,2,3,4,5 (2 shifts) - total 5 shifts`

Answer (score 6):

The number of swaps made in insertion sort is equal to the number of [inversions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) in the array (the number of pairs of elements that are out of order). There is a [well-known divide-and-conquer algorithm](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/cs423/lectures/divide-and-conquer-4up.pdf) for counting the number of inversions in an array that runs in time O(n log n). It's based on a slightly modified version of mergesort, and I think you shouldn't have too much trouble coding it up.

Comment: You're totally right, and I agree with you. However, I'm not sure this is an answer. More of a comment, really.

Comment: @AndyG It's definitely answer.

Comment: i tried and failed this one: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertion-sort/problem; i was able to write it with O(n * log(n) + n) using merge sort and then code to compare the remaining two arrays and it still fails the biggest arrays, i'm starting to believe there has to be a much simpler solution, does anyone know? merge part was n * log(n) and code to compare the two sorted arrays is O(n) -- for you to have an idea of the tests they apply, one has an input of 5 arrays which compose a 11mb file

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you're not correctly implementing insertion sort, what you've achieved is an inverse bubble-sort.

for a slightly less complex (yet with worse complexity :P) than @templatetypedef 's `O(n log n)` solution you can solve it in the same complexity of the sort `O(n^2)` by applying the correct implementation.

you should implement a function for `swap(int* array, int index_a, int index_b)` than count how many times this function was called.

this [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) to wikipedia has a good pseudo-code for you